# Swift: Search bar not showing up on viewController when coded programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, ibaction, programmatically-created

I am trying to add a search bar (with an IBAction method) to my viewController, but it is not showing up. Am I missing anything?

```
import UIKit

class SongrequestViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {



var tableView = UITableView()
var searchBar = UISearchBar()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: 370, height:400))
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
    
    searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBar.Style.prominent
    searchBar.placeholder = "Search for your song here..."
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.isTranslucent = false
    searchBar.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(searchBar)
}
```

The tableView is showing up, but not the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

View's frame will not be set in `viewDidLoad`. So `self.view.frame.size.width` might not return the correct value in `viewDidLoad`.

```
searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
```

Try adding the searchbar in viewDidAppear.

To detect text changes in searchbar, confirm to `UISearchBarDelegate` in your `SongrequestViewController` and implement its delegate method.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    print("search text: ", searchText)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know how I would be able to add something similar or the same as an IB  action method to the search bar?

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it did not work, but thanks anyways! I added another independent XIB file to my viewController to have the search bar show up.